# how to have a flexible flow Layout with show more Items in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, flowlayout, android-flexboxlayout

My Requirement is to create a layout like one in the image below

[image]

I can use the flexbox-layout library but the issue comes I only need to have 2 rows shown at first for example like the image above the layout will be restricted to show items at two maximum rows only, and on tapping on the +10 I want to see the whole items that will take the necessary height needed, any type of help or leads will really be appreciated here.

Comment: Use constraintlayout

Comment: @elbertrivas how can be ConstraintLayout useful here please explain?

Comment: Oh. I apologize, I have misunderstood your questions. By the way, are you showing these items using recylerview?

Comment: No, I haven't started implementation yet, still thinking about the possible ways of  implementing it, the image posted above is from the design provided... @elbertrivas